# Как интегрировать на сайт данные из профиля в Инстаграме?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

На сайте https://ivara.ru/ внизу главной страницы есть слайдер с фотками из Инстаграма, при клике на фотки открывается модальное окно с фоткой и комментариями к ней. Не пойму как такое реализовать и как импортировать данные из профиля в Инстаграме. Что для этого нужно? Нужен какой-то APi для Инстаграма или что? Как вся эта структура будет выглядеть в html? И как привязать все эти данные?

Answer (score 0):

Инстаграм позволяет получить доступ к своему API https://www.instagram.com/developer/